# How to make http calls with authorization in webapi project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, oauth-2.0, webapi

I would like to get some consultation and maybe some implementation to my problem.

Inside my webApi project I need to make another HTTP calls from HttpClient after results are received do some calculation and then return that data in my own Http method. But the problem I faced is that every time I make a HTTP call to that domain, I have to be authenticated with JWT token. How can I do this and how HttpCall would look like in service class? How that JWT token is going to be passed(I have my credentials to get receive token)? Is there somewhere a good example or tutorials I could follow up and solve this?

This is what I tried, am I going to right direction?

```
services.AddAuthentication(config => {
            // We check the cookie to confirm that we are authenticated
            config.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = "ClientCookie";
            config.DefaultSignInScheme = "ClientCookie";
            config.DefaultChallengeScheme = "OurServer";
        })           
            .AddOAuth("OurServer", config => {
                config.CallbackPath = "/oauth/callback";
                config.ClientId = "xxxxxxxxx.com";
                config.ClientSecret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";     
                config.AuthorizationEndpoint = "https://localhost:44352/auth"; // not implemented
                config.TokenEndpoint = "xxxxxx/token";

        });
```